# Assign a variable to xpath scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

Im using scrapy to crawl a webpage, the web page has 10+ links to crawl using |LinkExtractor, everything works fine but on the crawling of extracted links i need to get the page url. I have no other way to get the url but to use

```
response.request.url
```

How do i assign that value to

```
il.add_xpath('url', response.request.url)
```

If i do it like this i get error:

```
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py", line
100, in xpath
            raise ValueError(msg if six.PY3 else msg.encode("unicode_escape"))
        exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: http://www.someurl.com/news/45539/
title-of-the-news
```

And for description it is like this (just for refference):

```
il.add_xpath('descrip', './/div[@class="main_text"]/p/text()')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loader comes with two ways of adding attributes to the item, and is with `add_xpath` and `add_value`, so you should use something like:

```
...
il.add_value('url', response.url) # yes, response also has the url attribute
```